# What does this code do: using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))

Tags: c#

What does

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
```

do?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
new SqlConnection(connectionString)
```

creates a new `SqlConnection` instance against the supplied connection string.

```
SqlConnection cn = ...
```

assigns it to the new local variable `cn` (scoped to the `using` statement) that holds the constructed connection object.

```
using(...)
```

Is a `using` statement - it ensures that the connection is `Dispose()`-d at the end, even if an exception is thrown (in this case `Dispose()` means closing it / releasing to the pool etc)

The whole code is *essentially*:

```
{ // this { } scope is to limit the "cn"
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    try { // the body of the using block
        ...
    } finally { // dispose if not null
        if(cn != null) { cn.Dispose(); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It disposes the `SqlConnection` after it's not needed anymore. In this case `SqlConnection` can leave some unmanaged resources behind and you should clean them up. `SqlConnection` implements `IDisposable`, which means you can (should) call `Dispose` after you are done working with it.

It's basically a shorthand for:

```
try {
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

    // whatever other code
}
finally {
    if (cn != null)
    {
        cn.Dispose();
    }
}
```

When you use `using`, scope of `cn` is extended also outside `try` (to `finally`).

If you want to learn more, check [MSDN's article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28VS.80%29.aspx) regarding this topic.

Answer (score 2):

Makes sure the SqlConnection is destroyed at the end of the "using" scope

Answer (score 1):

the using statement can be applied to objects that implement the `IDisposable` interface.
At the end of the using scope Dispose is called on the object.

Answer (score 0):

This ensures releasing connection when control leaves using() {..} clause.

Leaving may occur as a result of exception, function return, break from loop, goto or normal leaving of scope. Very convenient.